# PHP Google map API for Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I need in my controller to calculate the time in the car as well as the distance between two addresses, so in PHP.

I'm on Symfony 4. So I'm looking for a bundle that allows me to do this.

I was on packagist, and I did not find anything that meets my expectations for Symfony 4, except this bundle: https://packagist.org/packages/fungio/google-map-bundle

But when I try to install it to test (him or all the other bundles related to google map), I get this kind of error:

> Could not find a version of package fungio/google-map-bundle matching
>   your minimum-stability (stable). Require it with an       explicit
>   version constraint allowing its desired stability.

EDIT: I added **"minimum-stability": "dev"** in my composer.json. The bundle is correctly downloading but I've this error now :

```
Symfony operations: 1 recipe (51cd62f67b65662de716f98b007199d1)
  - Configuring fungio/google-map-bundle (>=dev-master): From auto-generated recipe
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
!!
!!  In ParameterBag.php line 100:
!!  
!!    You have requested a non-existent parameter "templating.engines".  
!!  
!!
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

And if I try to download an other bundle like https://packagist.org/packages/geocoder-php/google-maps-provider

I've now :

```
composer require geocoder-php/google-maps-provider
Using version ^4.0@dev for geocoder-php/google-maps-provider
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.4.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - geocoder-php/google-maps-provider 4.0.0 requires geocoder-php/common-http ^4.0 -> satisfiable by geocoder-php/common-http[4.0.0, 4.0.0-beta1, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 4.0.x-dev].
    - geocoder-php/google-maps-provider 4.0.0-beta1 requires geocoder-php/common-http ^4.0 -> satisfiable by geocoder-php/common-http[4.0.0, 4.0.0-beta1, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 4.0.x-dev].
    - geocoder-php/google-maps-provider 4.0.0-beta2 requires geocoder-php/common-http ^4.0 -> satisfiable by geocoder-php/common-http[4.0.0, 4.0.0-beta1, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 4.0.x-dev].
    - geocoder-php/google-maps-provider 4.1.0 requires geocoder-php/common-http ^4.0 -> satisfiable by geocoder-php/common-http[4.0.0, 4.0.0-beta1, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 4.0.x-dev].
    - geocoder-php/google-maps-provider 4.2.0 requires geocoder-php/common-http ^4.0 -> satisfiable by geocoder-php/common-http[4.0.0, 4.0.0-beta1, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 4.0.x-dev].
    - geocoder-php/google-maps-provider 4.3.0 requires geocoder-php/common-http ^4.0 -> satisfiable by geocoder-php/common-http[4.0.0, 4.0.0-beta1, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 4.0.x-dev].
    - geocoder-php/google-maps-provider 4.4.0 requires geocoder-php/common-http ^4.0 -> satisfiable by geocoder-php/common-http[4.0.0, 4.0.0-beta1, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 4.0.x-dev].
    - geocoder-php/google-maps-provider 4.0.x-dev requires geocoder-php/common-http ^4.0 -> satisfiable by geocoder-php/common-http[4.0.0, 4.0.0-beta1, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 4.0.x-dev].
    - geocoder-php/common-http 4.0.x-dev requires psr/http-message-implementation ^1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - geocoder-php/common-http 4.2.0 requires psr/http-message-implementation ^1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - geocoder-php/common-http 4.1.0 requires psr/http-message-implementation ^1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - geocoder-php/common-http 4.0.0-beta1 requires psr/http-message-implementation ^1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - geocoder-php/common-http 4.0.0 requires psr/http-message-implementation ^1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for geocoder-php/google-maps-provider ^4.0@dev -> satisfiable by geocoder-php/google-maps-provider[4.0.0, 4.0.0-beta1, 4.0.0-beta2, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 4.3.0, 4.4.0, 4.0.x-dev].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: how do you install it?

Comment: Like this: ```composer require fungio/google-map-bundle```

Comment: You should require the symfony templating component too: composer require symfony/templating

If it doesn't resolve the issue, add this line to your services.yaml file inside parameters: templating:
    engines: ['twig', 'php']

Comment: I required the symfony/templating, and added the templating: engines: ['twig", 'php'] in services.yaml, but same problem, I've : ```You have requested a non-existent parameter "templating.engines". You cannot access nested array items, do you want to inject "templating" instead?  ```

Comment: Why are you explicitly looking for a **bundle** to solve that problem? Why not use any other of the packages offered at Packagist?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add a minimum-stability to dev in you composer.json

```
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. And no, that is not a good solution

Comment: @NicoHaase, Since that is not a good solution, I will not bother. I will however keep in mind to be more clear next time. Besides, dbrumann has got this under control I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with composer, not Symfony. As the error message mentions, composer can not find a stable version of the package.

If you are the maintainer then you can tag a version and packagist should update the page and show it as stable version or you can ask them to tag a release.

If you want to rely on the unstable version you can require the package with `@dev` like this:

```
composer require fungio/google-map-bundle:@dev-master
```

See: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links

Alternatively, you can modify your composer.json and set the minimum stability for dependencies to dev, but be aware that this might cause you to install unsafe packages accidentally.

See: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability

Your second composer issue is a bit tricky to decipher, but this line here is the hint:

```
geocoder-php/common-http XYZ requires psr/http-message-implementation ^1.0 -> no matching package found.
```

Your dependency `geocoder-php/google-maps-provider` relies on another dependency which requires an implementation for a PSR HTTP-Message. The package `psr/http-message-implementation` is only a virtual package and you have to pick an implementation that provides the required code. If you look for the package on packagist.org you can find multiple implementations. I can recommend `guzzlehttp/psr7` or `nyholm/psr7` but there are plenty more to choose from. Your command should then probably look something like:

```
composer require geocoder-php/google-maps-provider nyholm/psr7
```

Comment: Did you try this `composer require fungio/google-map-bundle@dev` already?

Comment: Yes, I tried and I've ```Could not find a matching version of package fungio/google-map-bundle@dev. Check the package spelling, your version constr   
  aint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (dev). ```

Comment: I have edited my answer for your other composer error. The problem with the missing parameter `templating.engines` in ParameterBag is something different. This hints to an error in your code or some misconfiguration. This is not composer-related, you can probably see the same error when running any Symfony command like `bin/console cache:clear`. Please open a new question for that and maybe include the service.yaml configuration or search for the parameter in your code/config and provide a snippet of that code.